# Hibernate sql annotation

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am using Hibernate to interface with SQL Server 2016/Azure SQL Server currently, and have been having a great time with it so far. In my database, I have implemented system versioned temporal tables. I want to map (preferably lazily) two more variables by annotation only to my Hibernate entity that represent the original ValidFrom and UpdatedBy fields from the temporal history of the appropriate table.

For example, I have a class and table for Accounts. The Account [minus nonrelated columns, constraints, etc] table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account] (
[Id]          INT                                         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[UpdatedBy]   INT                                         NOT NULL,
[ValidFrom]   DATETIME2 (7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL,
[ValidTo]     DATETIME2 (7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END   DEFAULT (CONVERT([datetime2],'9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999')) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Account.UpdatedById_Account.Id] FOREIGN KEY ([UpdatedBy]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Account] ([Id]),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([ValidFrom], [ValidTo])
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE=[dbo].[AccountHistory], DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK=ON));
```

The SQL statement to get the data that I want looks like this (I imagine that I would select only UpdatedBy or ValidFrom per annotation, but they are together now to be concise):

```
SELECT UpdatedBy, ValidFrom FROM dbo.Account
FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
WHERE ValidFrom IN
(
SELECT MIN(ValidFrom) OVER (Partition BY Id) AS ValidFrom
FROM dbo.Account
FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
WHERE ID = $(passedInIdOfThisEntity)
)
```

Finally, my Hibernate entity/pojo looks something like this (again, redacting irrelevant variables):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UpdatedBy")
    private Account updatedBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "ValidFrom", nullable = false, length = 27, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date validFrom;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "ValidTo", nullable = false, length = 27, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date validTo;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "updatedBy")
    private Set<Account> accountsUpdated;

    // This is a stub of what I'm hoping you can help me add
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "ValidFrom", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, insertable = false, updatable = false, somesqlselect = SQL_STATEMENT_FROM_ABOVE)
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name = "UpdatedBy", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, insertable = false, updatable = false, somesqlselect = SQL_STATEMENT_FROM_ABOVE)
    private Account createdBy

    // ... getters and setters below
}
```

I have been using Hibernate to a great extent, but have had trouble finding information on this, though I have found and used examples of implementing native queries for retrieving entities instead of using criteria queries. If you can help me solve this riddle to allow me to continue using criteria queries to retrieve data and populate these fields through annotation on demand, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If I understand what you want, you should do a @ManyToOne and map the other table instead of trying to make it a single column value with a native subquery.

Comment: So, you are saying to have an Account originalAccount with a mapping to AccountHistory? I'm not sure if that would work or not for what I'm doing, since the history table is really supposed to be queried indirectly by proxy through the main table. The history table has no PK, can't be written to, and all of the time based query dialogue only works on it's parent table, Account. If I mapped a new entity with a sql query I may be able to do a lazy load that way though

Comment: Oh I see now.  I think your best bet is to a Native Query https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html

Comment: I don't see in this documentation how I would map the class variables Account createdBy or Date createdOn via annotation with a native query though. I am working on a generic abstract parent class that will check if the variables are null and perform the native query if necessary, but that seems like a lot of run around and less concise

Comment: I don't know if JPA/Hibernate allows a column to be generated by a dynamic SQL query.  If you couldn't find anything by Googling and no one here answers that may be the issue.  Sometimes, in cases like this.  I use Spring's JdbcTemplate instead and use a rowmapper to construct the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporal table constructs that you've described isn't something that I am aware that JPA or even Hibernate support natively.  These are likely new features of the ANSI SQL standard which haven't made their way into proper support.

That said, that doesn't mean you cannot use frameworks like Hibernate to accomplish the task.  As indicated in the comments, you can specify a named query and execute that in order to get the attributes you desire.

From a JPA 2.1 perspective, you use `@SqlResultSetMapping` and `@ConstructorResult`.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
  name = "Account.getWithTemporalAttributes",
  classes = {
    @ConstructorResult(
      targetClass = com.company.domain.AccountTemporalDetails.class,
      columns = {
        @ColumnResult(name = "col1"),
        @ColumnResult(name = "col2")
      })
  })
```

To use this, you would do the following:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery( 
                 "SELECT a.col1 as col1, a.col2 as col2 FROM Account a",
                 "Account.getWithTemporalAttributes");
List<AccountTemporalDetails> results = query.getResultList();
```

That should allow you to use Native SQL queries, mapping them to a POJO which you can easily then use within your application without having to write boilerplate.  The `@ConstructorResult` annotation is meant to mimic the JPQL `SELECT NEW` syntax.  So you would just need to make sure that `AccountTemporalDetails` had a constructor that takes those arguments with the right types.